# Where to save customized functional_test template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to customize the controller test which is generated by `rails g scaffold`. I found the template file at

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/test_unit/scaffold/templates/functional_test.rb.tt

After downloading it I made the changes I want to apply but have no idea in which directory I have to save it. Which one is the correct one so that I can use it in my Rails project?

Rails Version: 5.2

Comment: Did you check this? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates

Comment: Did you try `/lib/templates/test_unit/scaffold/templates/functional_test.rb.tt`?

Comment: @gasc Of course I checked the documentation.

Comment: @max That path doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @wintermeyer, did you figure this out? Having the same issue right now..